# How to map private fields in FluentNHibernate using DefaultAutomappingConfiguration

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

The guidance given here http://fluentnhibernate.org/blog/2010/05/23/feature-focus-fields.html suggests that from V1.1 the automapping feature of Fluent NHibernate supports mapping to private fields.

So given the following code, NHiberate should be able to map to the `myValue` field.

```
public class SomeEntity
{   
   private string myValue;
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class DomainAutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(FluentNHibernate.Member member)
    {
        return (member.IsProperty && member.IsPublic && member.CanWrite) ||
               (member.IsField && member.IsPrivate);
     }
 }
```

However when I run this code and try to map, I get the following exception:

> NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException : Could not find a getter for property 'myValue' in
>   class.....

I am using FluentNHibernate 1.1 and NHibernate 3.0.0.2001

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
private string myValue;
```

To:

```
private string myValue {get;set;}
```

I am not sure if this will do it for you, but the error you are receiving is the lack of the {get;} when designating the private field.  Hopefully this will put you on the right track. I have not tried mapping private fields.

Good luck.